# SwiftUI - Matched Geometry Effect Size doesn't match

Tags: swift, swiftui

Consider the following sample:

```swift
struct MatchedGeometryHeight: View {
    
    @State private var mainHeight: CGFloat = 100
    @Namespace private var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Main Height")
                        Slider(value: $mainHeight, in: 10...200)
                    }
                }.padding(.vertical, 20)
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .foregroundColor(.green.opacity(0.8))
                    .frame(height: mainHeight)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "dynamic",
                                           in: namespace)
                
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eleifend risus id laoreet imperdiet. Praesent molestie lectus id sem ornare ultricies. Nam faucibus ante erat.")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .shadow(radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2))
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "dynamic",
                                           in: namespace,
                                           properties: .size,
                                           isSource:  false)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This produces:

[image: Staggered Height Changes]

I'm expecting the blue rectangle to match the green one's. However, what happens instead is that the blue rectangle tightly hugs its text rather than the geometry effect.

Now, because this is a simple example, I know I could fix that by using the following modifier:

```swift
.frame(minWidth: .zero,
       maxWidth: .infinity,
       minHeight: .zero,
       maxHeight: .infinity)
```

[image: Smooth Height Changes]

But unfortunately in the real world, I want to be able to be able to pass generic contents to those Rectangles (think cards with varying amounts of data). When that happens, setting the `.frame` modifier like previously mentioned doesn't help at all.

[image: Complex view doesn't resize]

From what I see, it seem like a view will refuse using a smaller size than what its own contents require.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try putting a Spacer to the beginning and end of the VStack (the text's parent)

Comment: You ask "How can I achieve this?" but don't really explain what you expect to happen. Do you want to start hiding elements? Scale the text size? How do you see your example view shrink to that small size? Nothing would be left of it.

Comment: @CasperZandbergen Sorry I should have mentioned this, the "child" views will in fact be put behind the "parent" with some offset, to create a card deck effect. Therefore I don't mind at all that the contents are squished, since they won't be seen in that state. As long as it's all clipped to bounds

Comment: @Skwiggs Ah, okay. That sounds doable. Will you be reapplying the bounty that ran out to the question?

Comment: @CasperZandbergen don't remember putting any bounty myself 